# mock domain class created by another domain class with spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-domain-class, spock

I'm trying to test a domain class called EnityContact. Inside that class there is a method called initialize which populates some fields when needed. in order to do that the method creates instances of some other domain classes: AisUser, Entity and CPerson. AisUser is the domain class returned by the call to SecurityUtil.retrieveCurrentAisUser(false).

```
class EntityContact extends BaseObject implements Initializable{

    ....

    @Override
    void initialize() {
        println "initaliazing"
        isMain = false
        creationDate = new Date()
        createdBy = CPerson.get(SecurityUtil.retrieveCurrentAisUser(false).id)
        entity = new Entity()
        entity.setId(Long.valueOf(0)) //Id has to be initialized with some value
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do is find a way to return mocks of those classes that i define in my specification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy [you can mock static methods using MetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mocking+Static+Methods+using+Groovy).

```
SecurityUtil.metaClass.'static'.retrieveCurrentAisUser = { boolean param ->
}
```